# How do you know if a function only yields a certain kind of number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let's say that we have a function $3n^2-3n+13$. How do I know if the function only yields prime number without exhausting all the possibilities by trial and error?

Comment: It doesn't. Think of a clever choice of $n$ that kills primality.

Comment: No (non-constant) polynomial with integer coefficients yields prime numbers for all integer arguments.

Answer (score 8):

If your function is $f(n)=3n^{2}-3n+13$ by putting $n=13$ you will have $f(n)=13(39-3+1)$ that is not prime, even without thinking! why you ask it?

Comment: It is really $13(39-3+1)$ but the message is the same.  Generally, for any polynomial you can set $n$ to any factor of the constant term.  This takes care of all polynomials except those with a constant term of $\pm 1$

Comment: @RossMillikan, you are correct. But I wondered as I saw his question when he was accent on without **exhausting** all the possibilities by trial and error ! But by what you said here I think he will earn better thought and will not be bothered on same case when numbers will be changed.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh: Like your approach. +1